# Using Recursion / Getting 'None' attached to my output

Tags: python, recursion

for some reason I cannot seem to wrap my head around returning things properly. I am trying to get strings to become acronyms using recursion (ignore that my code is sloppy lol) but it just attaches None to the end of my desired output!

How can I fix this? Again, recursion is necessary for this problem!

```
def recAbbrev(lst):
    'return a single string with the first character of all the strings in a list combined and capitalized.'
    if len(lst)== [] :
        return 0
    
    if len(lst)>0:
        if type(lst[0])==list:
            return 1 + recAbbrev(lst[0])
        else:
            acronym = ""
            letter = ""
            letter = letter + lst[0][:1]
            letter = letter.upper()
            acronym = acronym + letter
            print(acronym, end = '')  
            return recAbbrev(lst[1:])
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\17734\OneDrive\Desktop\fall 2021\csc242\homework\csc242hw7-s.py", line 80, in <module>
    print(recEvenNumbers(['c','a','t',' ' ,0,'h',1,'a',2,'t',100]))
  File "C:\Users\17734\OneDrive\Desktop\fall 2021\csc242\homework\csc242hw7-.py", line 49, in recEvenNumbers
    return recEvenNumbers(lst[1:])
  File "C:\Users\17734\OneDrive\Desktop\fall 2021\csc242\homework\csc242hw7-s.py", line 49, in recEvenNumbers
    return recEvenNumbers(lst[1:])
  File "C:\Users\17734\OneDrive\Desktop\fall 2021\csc242\homework\csc242hw7-As.py", line 49, in recEvenNumbers
    return recEvenNumbers(lst[1:])
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "C:\Users\17734\OneDrive\Desktop\fall 2021\csc242\homework\csc242hw7-s.py", line 47, in recEvenNumbers
    return recEvenNumbers(evens)
  File "C:\Users\17734\OneDrive\Desktop\fall 2021\csc242\homework\csc242hw7-.py", line 44, in recEvenNumbers
    elif type(lst[0]) == int:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Starting recAbbrev
None
CPUNone
RAMNone
Starting recEvenNumbers

```
thank you!
```

Comment: A few simple `inputs` (string) and outputs will be very helpful.  Even though it seems clear to under this Problem.

Comment: `if len(lst)== [] :` is wrong. If the list is empty, then its length is zero, the number zero, not the empty list. You should write `if len(lst) == 0:` instead. `len(lst) == []` is never going to be true, since `len(lst)` is a number and `[]` is a list.

Comment: BTW, a simple python function to get an acronym out of a string: `def acronym(s): return ''.join(w[0].upper() for w in s.split())`

Answer (score 1):

`len` returns an `int` and you don't want to return 0

```
    if len(lst)== 0:
        return ''
```